# Maximum Length does not work Web API 2 Model

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api2

I have a model class to receive data, I want to limit the text input to 10 char but when I try it in my test methods it accepts more than that. Here is my code:

```
public class Post
{
    [Required]
    public string userId { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(1, MinimumLength = 10)] 
    public string dataText { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int dataType { get; set; }
}
[TestMethod()]
public void AddPostTest()
{
    SQLDB db = new SQLDB();
    Post userpost = new Post();
    userpost.userId = "1";
    userpost.dataText = "fgfdgfdgfdgdfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgdfgfdg";
    userpost.dataType = 1;

    Assert.IsTrue(db.AddPost(userpost));
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are using minimum length not the max length attribute

Comment: Well your max length is 1, and the min length is 10.  How should that work exactly?  Per the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/StringLengthAttribute.cs#L82) for `StringLengthAttribute`, that would result in an exception.  What is `AddPost`?  It's apparently ignoring the attribute entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax of StringLengthAttribute is as follows: Reference [StringLengthAttribute MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public StringLengthAttribute(
    int maximumLength
)

[Required, StringLength(MaximumLength, MinimumLength)] 
public string dataText { get; set; }
```

In your case you used MaxLength value = 1 and MinLength value = 10 which is incorrect.
Please swap both the values

```
[Required, StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 1)] 
public string dataText { get; set; }
```

or just use max value

```
[Required, StringLength(10)] 
public string dataText { get; set; }
```

Comment: what is the name of property? is it dataText or postText? In above comment you just changed name of property. I am not understanding what you want to say. Please elaborate

Comment: dataText sorry.

Comment: [Required, StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 1)] public string dataText { get; set; }

Comment: I updated my answer, still I would recommend you to write **Required and StringLength attributes** in two different square bracket and use only max value.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone uses a parameter variable instead of a property then you can try this

```
 public object Myfunc( [FromQuery(Name = "yourfieldname"), Required,StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)] string yourfieldname)
```